# How do I override distributionManagement from the command line?

Tags: java, maven

I have this in my POMs

```
  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
          <id>zzzz</id>
          <name>releases</name>
          <url>https://jfrog.io/sdfsdf/repo</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
          <id>zzzzz</id>
          <name>snapshots</name>
          <url>https://jfrog.io/sdfsdf/repo</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement
```

How do I override this with command line arg to mvn? Can I do this without modifying the POM files?

I tried this but it seems the argument is totally ignored:
`mvn deploy DaltDeploymentRepository=zzzzz::default::https://jfrog.io/sdfsdf/repo`

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Maybe we can find another solution for the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you can do that using ./m2/settings.xml and install -s key on cmdline